# Deserialize variable for promotionConfig

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am trying to pass variable (repoName) with the repo name to the [promotionConfig](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-PromotingBuildsinArtifactory) parameter *targetRepo* and *sourceRepo* but I get this error in Jenkins:

**Build result notified
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.PromotionConfig["targetRepo"])**

I am using inside the promotionConfig:

```
...
'targetRepo'         : '${repoName}-release-local',
...
'sourceRepo'         : '${repoName}-snapshot-local',
...
```

The variable repoName

```
echo "Repo name is ${repoName}"
```

Output: Repo name is **test-repo**

Anyone know the right way to pass a variable to the promotionConfig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use double quotes to pass variables inside string.

```
def var = "${repoName}".toString()
...
'targetRepo'         : "" + var + "-release-local",   
...
'sourceRepo'         : "" + var + "-snapshot-local",
...
```

Comment: That does not work. Error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.PromotionConfig["targetRepo"])

Comment: Interesting, I got it to work like this:

    def rName = "${repoName}".toString()

    'targetRepo'         : '' + rName
 + '-release-local’,
    …
    ‘sourceRepo'         : '' + rName
 + '-release-local’,

It looks weird. Is this correct?

Comment: yes it looks correct. what is type of repoName variable?

Comment: That is just a string that I got from this:
`token = "${env.JOB_NAME}".tokenize(‘/‘)`
`repoName = token[0] `